# Translating the concept of the "man with a van"

Tags: vocabulaire, professions

I am having trouble finding a suitable translation for "man with a van" (i.e., small time delivery driver service). In particular, how would this service be listed in a directory? Can anyone make a suggestion please?

Comment: Fortunately you gave the translation. Because "man in a van" in French pretty sounds like a pervert and/or a paedophile in a van! :-)

Answer (score 3):

The general term for someone making deliveries is *livreur*. Although, in the case you describe, I'd go for **coursier livreur** (definition for [coursier](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/coursier), see 2nd tab) which is hinting at the 'small time' part (neither go very far nor transport too big packages).

As a sidenote, the second part is sometimes dropped altogether to have the simple **coursier**.